# How can I configure a test environment with Falcon

Tags: python, falconframework

I started to write a small REST API using Python with Falcon and Gunicorn. I would like to write some integration tests and I am not sure how to set up a proper test environment (for example to switch to another database). Do you have some good advice or tutorials?

My current idea is to maybe introduce some middleware and to provide a header. If the header is set, I could switch to my test configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely don't add middleware for the sole purpose of integration testing. What you should do is set up some configuration files for your server to use. Dev, Test, and Prod is a decent setup. Each file can point to a different database and have different ports for your server. I'm sure you will even be able to have Dev and Test servers up and running at the same time on your personal computer without any issues. Python has a build in [config](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html) module that you can use. You can set environment variables in your shell so your server knows which configuration file to use. E.G. in bash `FALCON_ENV='DEV'` Then in python you can use the [os](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html) module to get the environment variable - `os.environ['FALCON_ENV']`. Hope that helps, feel free to ask any more questions.

Comment: Thank your for that answer. It definitely sounds like a solid approach. However I already have a huge docker stack running and I would like to keep the stack as small as possible. However a configuration per server probably is the best practice

Comment: I feel your pain. In my current docker setups, I have some docker-compose override files to switch between container configurations. So you could have a docker-compose override script that builds test rather than dev. Then write a script  to do ```docker-compose down``` && ```docker-compose up -fdocker-compose.test.yml```

Comment: Furthermore, docker containers are usually pretty lightweight, so you should check your memory usage before opting out of spinning up some new containers.

Comment: Well yes. I even think about starting the same container twice and maybe just linking a different config file into it, but linking the same folder containing my python scripts. Never tried that before, but maybe it works

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can set the environment variable from docker to choose your config file- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substituting-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Answer (score 1):

You might want try using the virtual testing environment and testing helpers provided by falcon core:

http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/testing.html

Comment: Yes. Ok, you want specifically test how falcon is playing with gunicorn ?

Comment: No, I want to test the falcon environment together with other services I am currently implementing. The API is just delivering some parts of a bigger picture